# Why does Jetpack Compose LazyColumn MutableLiveData only recompose on first button click?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Learning Kotlin and Jetpack Compose in Android Studio.  Trying to understand recomposition.

#### The following code only recomposes on the first button click - why?

Output is shown below my code.  Basically, **the first time I click the Add New Item button the screen recomposes perfectly, but then it does not recompose again.**  However, if you look at the LogCat, you can see that it's still working, just not updating the screen.  What am I missing?

#### View Model

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val listLiveData: LiveData<List<Int>>
        get() = newListLiveData

    private val newList = ArrayList<Int>()
    private val newListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()

    fun addNewListItem(listItem: Int) {
        newList.add(listItem)
        newListLiveData.value = newList
        println("**** addNewListItem($listItem)")
    }
}
```

#### Home Screen Scaffolding and Content

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    model: MainViewModel
) {

    val stuff by model.listLiveData.observeAsState(emptyList())

    Scaffold(
        content = { Content(model, stuff) }
    )

}

@Composable
fun Content(
    model: MainViewModel = MainViewModel(),
    stuff: List<Int>
) {
        LazyColumn() {
            items(items = stuff){ index ->
                Text("$index")
            }
        }
        Button(
            onClick = { model.addNewListItem((0..10).random()) },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Add Random Item to List")
        }
}
```

#### LogCat Output

```
I/System.out: **** addNewListItem(0)  <-- Recomposes fine here 
I/System.out: **** addNewListItem(2)  <-- Does not recompose
I/System.out: **** addNewListItem(5)  <-- Does not recompose
I/System.out: **** addNewListItem(6)  <-- Does not recompose
I/System.out: **** addNewListItem(4)  <-- Does not recompose
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Thank you

Comment: How are you observing `listLiveData`?

Comment: You need to show the calling site of this Composable for us to be able to debug this.

Comment: @gpunto Good point!  I just edited the post to include that.  See above.

Comment: @MARSK Good point! I just edited the post to include that.  See above.

Comment: Does the value on the screen remain the same after the first recomposition?

Comment: @MARSK yes it does - no changes - just remains there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly speaking, as long as you do not have to do with interoperability with the View system, AVOID using anything other than the built-for-Compose `MutableState<T>` objetcs. The ultra-boilerplate code of yours can simply be replaced by

```
ViewModel{
 val cleanList by mutableStateListOf<Item>() // Initialized as an Empty list of 'Item's
 fun addItem(item: Item){
  cleanList.add
 }
}
```

Within Composables,

```
@Composable
MyComposable(
 list: List<Item>,
 onAddItem: (Item) -> Unit // Receive Item, return Unit
) {
 Button { // This is on-Click, assume
  onAddItem(/*Add Item Here, per logic*/)
 }
}
```

Call it anywhere like so

```
MyComposable(list = viewModel.cleanList, onAddItem = viewModel::addItem)
```

This is some fine code here. Easy to read, free of boilerplate, bafflingly beautiful and clean as a crystal.

Leverage the beauty of Compose, and ditch the ugly legacy crap.

Comment: Also, it is not a good practice to pass your model around. You should always pass only what is required. Like I passed the value, and the method to add items, not the entire viewModel. Passing the getter as well as the setter if you need one, is always a good rule of thumb.

Comment: I'm going to try to implement this.  Thank you for looking at this.  Assuming it works, I'll be back to mark this answer.

Comment: I changed it to ``val cleanList = mutableStateListOf<Int>()`` to get it to work.

Comment: I'm always confused whether it is delegated or not, but yeah, whatever works for you.